# Create big Jar(desktop) of android/desktop gdx project

Tags: java, android, jar, libgdx

I've managed to setup, with use of the gdx project generator, a project, that runs both on android and desktop. (using Android Studio 0.8.2)
The generator has generated several projects like, desktop, android, html, ios and core.
(at the moment, i'm not interrested in ios/html)

My question is: How can I configure Gradle to build one big Jar file, I can run directly from windows, for the desktop configuration? (So I can spread my game as beta for friends)

I've seen something like this in my build.gradle:

```
task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from { configurations.compile.collect { zipTree(it) } }
    from files(project.assetsDir);

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }

}
```

But this doesn't generate a complete Jar with resources  (android assets)

(not sure, but I haven't found any big Jars yet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you used the  gdx project generator (this:  https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle), you should be able to create your runnable jar using this command:

```
gradlew desktop:dist
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, I am using AndroidStudio, Instead of doing this manually, can I build/run Desktop version from inside AndroidStudio? I tried but couldn't make it work. :(